# How to make a HTML/CSS/JS iOS style slide transition?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm not using jQuery mobile. It is too large of a library to do what I want.

I want a simple slide transition effect.

E.g, you click a box and it "slides in a new page" press a button on that page and it "slides back" to the original content.

This is all I need. Is there a simple library that does this or some easy code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Flexslider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) is pretty good for mobile. It has some custom functions for slide functionality and  is responsive out-of-the-box. You can also do dynamic heights and looping by just setting some attributes in the config object.

You are also not limited by the content type. You can use html in divs just as easily as an image or video.

Comment: That seems to be more of an image gallery slider. What I meant is that a whole new content area "slides in and overlays" the current page and then slides back out.

Comment: It is an image gallery by default, but you dont have to just put images in the html, you can do content as well. Here is an example of a site my company built using flexslider as the main content navigation: https://www.facebook.com/myemdserono/app_362800527167129